# Self-training better commit practice in git

Tags: git, github, workflow, commit

## The Problem

I’ve noticed that some repositories on GitHub are particular about what they consider an acceptable history when reviewing a Pull Request.  Their reasoning for this is that a repository’s history should have a high signal-to-noise ratio; that `git log` should “tell a story”.

In terms of *philosophy*, I strongly agree with this.  But in *practice*, I’m probably one of the worst offenders against neat, orderly commit behavior.

**And I want to change that.**

## Where I’ve been

I’ve tried to be mindful, and “just try to remember”…but it really doesn’t work for me.  I’m too scatterbrained.  I can start a feature branch (or bugfix branch, or whatever) with the intent of keeping my work focused on a particular topic.  Sometimes that topic might be “improve documentation”, “refactor this class”, or “tweak the output of this program”.  But before I know it, I’m doing a little bit of everything, and by the time my feature (or bug, or whatever) branch is ready for merging, it’s a mix of the topic it was *supposed* to be, plus a bunch of other stuff as well.

### Worst Offenders

This is true in general, but if I had to highlight a few of my own worst habits, probably the most “noisy” such edits are:

- whitespace tweaks
- small rewrites of chunks of code for readability
- add short (but frequent) comments to help code "scannability"
- renaming variables so that their names are (a) more descriptive of the variable's purpose, and (b) are consistent across a file/component/project

So, I enjoy doing all these things, and I’m proud of the work that I do.  But I wish I knew a  way to do it such that my project history was more orderly/logical.

## …And now, the question

**Does anybody know how a scatterbrain can become better at this?**

(Tools, mental models, diagrams…anything is welcome!)

Comment: One way to enforce this might be to create as much stories as can logically think of. Prioritize them semantically. Strictly Code for only one story at a time.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to fight who you are with git. Look into patch adding (`git add -p`), which will let you choose and commit only part(s) of your changes. If you use Vim, the [fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) plugin makes this really simple. Emacs users have [magit](https://github.com/magit/magit), though I've not tried it. I've heard it's also good at simplifying patch adding. Also, if you're just commiting away on, say, master, and realize it should've been a branch for the last 5 commits, just `git branch topic` to drop a topic branch head where you are, `git reset --hard HEAD~5` to back up master 5 commits, then `git checkout topic` and continue.

- whitespace tweaks

If it's the last commit, just make/save the tweaks, add the change, and `git commit --amend` to fold them into the previous commit. If it's two or more commits back, commit the change to a new one, then `git rebase -i` and move the latest (bottom-most) commit line up to below the one you want to change, and change the 'pick' at the beginning of the line to 'fixup', then save and quit.

- small rewrites of chunks of code for readability

Again, `git rebase -i` and change `pick` to `edit` on any commits you want to tweak, save and quit, edit the file(s), add it/them, `git rebase --continue`, repeat as necessary.

- add short (but frequent) comments to help code "scannability"

Nothing wrong with that.

- renaming variables...

Commits like these are fine, and really fast to code review:

```
* 8071179 Refactor all foo to bar across library
* 334464a Rename foo.save to foo.export for clarity
```

You can use the body of the commit messages to explain why, if you feel it'll help future users of your commits, including yourself.

Answer (score 0):

W.r.t. fixing whitespace and code style, there are tools for several languages that can do that for you or help you with that. E.g. C has `indent`, Python has `reindent.py` et cetera. You can either run these programs yourself or automatically at each check-in using a commit hook in git.

My favorite though is to run checkers from my editor every time I save a file (using [syntastic](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2736) in [vim](http://www.vim.org/)). This gives you immediate feedback. You can see it as automated learning. Syntastic has checkers for *many* languages.

With regard to being scatterbrained, train yourself to work and finish the task at hand. If you see something else during that task, write down the where and what and put it aside to fix later. Unless it is e.g. a trivial typo. Just fix that and go on.